# Compute the row and column totals for an iterable of tuples

Tags: python, list, iterable

This requires to `yield` the results as they are computed. should not store all of the data at any point. This should support streams of data larger than memory.

> For each row add an int at the beginning that is the total of the row.
>
> Once the entire input has been processed add a final row with the
>   totals of every column in the input. This should include the initial
>   total column and you should treat columns that are missing on a given
>   row as zeros.
>
> The row totals are the first column instead of the last
>   (as is more common) because it makes rows of different length easier
>   to handle.

For example:

```
    def func([(1,2,3), (4,5)]) = [(6,1,2,3),(9,4,5),(15,5,7,3)]
```

Comment: You might get more help if you identified the language.

Comment: I don't understand the question; could you clarify it?

Comment: What have you written so far, and how is it deficient?

Comment: Your example contains an error, the result should be `[(6,1,2,3),(9,4,5),(15,5,7,3)]` (the last column of the total line should be 3, not 4.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully you will learn something from this:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def func(rows):
    totals = []
    for row in rows:
        row = (sum(row),) + row
        totals = [sum(col) for col in izip_longest(totals, row, fillvalue=0)]
        yield row
    yield tuple(totals)

>>> list(func([(1,2,3), (4,5)]))
[(6, 1, 2, 3), (9, 4, 5), [15, 5, 7, 3]]
```

This code iterates over all of the rows yielding a tuple comprising the summed columns and the original columns.

[`izip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) pairs items in the current row with the corresponding item in `totals` to maintain a running total of each column. `izip_longest()` was chosen because it can handle rows of different lengths and you can supply a fill value (0 in this case) for missing items.